# Azure Pipelines Deploy Stage Failing without Error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

The deploy stage of the pipeline fails without error after build stage completes successfully.
Enabling system diagnostics does not give in any additional information (see the screenshot below).

[image]

The following pipelines yaml file was used:

```
trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
    - job: Build
      displayName: Build
      pool:
        vmImage: $(vmImageName)
      steps:
      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
          script: |
            ls -la
          
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy Notebook Instance Stage
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: 'myenv.default'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - task: CmdLine@2
              inputs:
                script: echo Some debug text!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used your script and I change only `environment` as I don't have `myenv.default` and all is fine.

[image]

Please double check your environment setting.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it turns out the environment was the problem. Not sure how that happened.